# Unable to output the result of bitwise operation in standard output stream (cout) of C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, bitwise-operators

Whenever I am trying to execute

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
cout<< a ^ b;
```

The compiler showing an error and at the same time when I am executing

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
printf("%d", a ^ b);
```

It was working fine,
What could be the problem behind it ?

Comment: Show the exact error

Comment: Operator `<<` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than  operator `^`, so your expression is evaluated as `(cout<< a) ^ b;`

Answer (score 3):

According to [C++ Operator Precedence - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `^` has lower precedence than `<<`.

This makes `cout<< a ^ b` be interpreted as `(cout<< a) ^ b` and this operation is not supported.

`cout<< (a ^ b);` will work.